# How to use css styling that the available width is used in the one column and the other column use width it needs

Tags: html, css, flexbox, display

I need css styling for 2 columns. The first column should use the complete width and the second column next to it should use only the width it needs. How can i do that? Is there any way to do this with display: flex?

**Example:**

"-" = whitespace

if second column is display: none, the first column should use width 100%

`[First-Column-------------------------------------------------------]`

and if not

`[First-Column------------------------------------------------][HELLO]`

`[First-Column-------------------------------------------][HELLOHELLO]`

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question to fit those guidelines. Show us what you have attempted so far. Note that Stackoverflow is not a coding service and we expect you to have done some research on the topic and come up with an attempt at solving your problem. With that said, I would look into existing CSS frameworks, since they have excellent responsive design and good documentation. An example would be Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with flexbox. Just use `flex: 1` for the first child and `flex: 0` for the second.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  color: white;
}

.child1 {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
}

.child2 {
  flex: 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child child1">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="child child2">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

If you hide the second child, the result looks like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  color: white;
}

.child1 {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
}

.child2 {
  flex: 0;
  background: blue;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child child1">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="child child2">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you want items with only width of the content you could use this:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  color: white;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.child1 {
  background: red;
}

.child2 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child child1">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="child child2">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost, because if you will write "test test test" in your second child, it will break the line ... i dont know why, but basically its right. Hmm do you know a solution for that?

Comment: yes, just use `white-space: nowrap;` for the second child.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with below code:

```css
.mainDiv, .mainDiv div{
  display: block;
}
.mainDiv .firstDiv{
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
.mainDiv .secondDiv{
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="firstDiv"> First Div </div>
  <div class="secondDiv"> Second Div </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP wanted a solution with `display: flex`.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.main{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>[First-Column------------------------------------------------]</div>
  <div> [HELLO]</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this does not use the full width of the parent.